# Удаление NET Framework 4.6 из Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows

Суть: работаю с софтом для полноценной работы которого нужен Framework 4.0, чтобы его поставить нужно снести NET Framework 4.6 (который судя по программе версион детектор установлен с ошибкой Unknown build:394271).

В удалении програм его нет
NET Framework Cleanup Tool не пашет

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то в Windows 8.1 включён .NET Framework 4.5.1. Если Вам нужен именно 4.0, то придётся устанавливать Windows 7.

Comment: А в компонентах Windows рядом со списком установленных программ?